# Looping through query in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Dim strCell As String
Dim strProv As String
Dim strTextEmail As String
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")


Dim StrBCC As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Staff Query")

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()

With rst
Do Until .EOF

strCell = Nz([CellPhone], "0")
strProv = Nz([CellProvider], "0")
MsgBox [CellPhone]
MsgBox [CellProvider]

If strCell = "0" Or strProv = "0" Then
    MsgBox "MISSING DATA: Please double check the agent name, cell phone number and provider are entered in the staff table."
Else
         Dim Clean As String
         Dim Pos, A_Char
         Pos = 1
         For Pos = 1 To Len(strCell)
            A_Char = Mid(strCell, Pos, 1)
            If A_Char >= "0" And A_Char <= "9" Then
              Clean = Clean + A_Char
            End If
         Next Pos
         strCell = Clean
         strProv = DLookup("[EmailExt]", "CellProviders", "[CellProvider]='" & strProv & "'")
strTextEmail = strCell & strProv
End If


StrBCC = StrBCC & strTextEmail & ";"

rst.MoveNext
Loop

End With
StrBCC = Left(StrBCC, Len(StrBCC) - 1)

Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
oMail.BCC = StrBCC
oMail.Display

Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
```

I am trying to loop through the query "Staff Query" to send a text to everyone in it. I have everything working except the fact that it wont loop through the query, it loops through the first record on the form I open it on and it wont move. 
Anyone have any suggestions for this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try rst.MoveFirst before you start the  loop

Comment: as well as `MoveFirst` check whether there are records in the first place - `If Not .BOF AND Not .EOF THEN: DO UNTIL .EOF.....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not reading the values from the recordset into your local variables. What you do right now, is reading the values from form controls (I guess). So these will not change if you move to the next record in the recordset.

Change the beginning of the loop like this:

```
With rst
  Do Until .EOF
    strCell = Nz(rst.Fields("CellPhone").Value, "0")
    strProv = Nz(rst.Fields("CellProvider").Value, "0")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple but overlooked that fact.

Comment: One last question, The phone numbers keep getting added on to the next record when they appear in the bcc field. I'm not sure were to reset the fields or am i attaching them wrong?

Comment: Well, I don't see where you are sending the mail, but I did not question it, as it wasn't part of the question. - Anyway, you are appending the current number to your variable strBCC. If you don't want that, just set it to the new value: strBCC = strTextEmail

Comment: i figured it out but thank you for the response. Had to set the clean variable to "" before each iteration of the loop.